# How can i execute android firebase multiple childeventlistiner in sequence order

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have 4 ChildEventListener in one activity. When activity launches 4th ChildEventListener executes 1st then 3rd, 2nd, 1st and some time it will be in reverse order 1,2,3,4. so it is not loading sequentially. ChildEventListener listeners example are mentioned below.

```
 AfirebaseDatabaRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

BfirebaseDatabaRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why on earth You want them to execute sequentially. They are listeners they will execute whenever they should be. You need to write your logic accordingly or create a state mechanism if you are truely desperate for sequence execution

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) right now. It also sounds like the expected behavior: the listener will fire in order that their data is loaded. What are you trying to accomplish with these listeners? Maybe there is a simple way to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand these listeners well, callback is being called for the node that is registered to it only this node no one else, so if you have multiple nodes and every node has callback registered to it, when change happens to any node the corresponding callback ONLY will be triggered, so the sequence should be changes in the nodes not the callbacks, i hope this answers your question.